# make the arrow work in the hover with the whole anchor

Tags: html, css

like you can se when i put my cursor over the arrow that made a tranform of 90deg, but i want to make the same behaivor when i put my cursor over all the anchor not only when i put the cursor over the arrow.
i was thinking giving to both the same hover but obviusly don't work
and also, how can i give it some kind of slow transition, because the transformation is like too hard, i want to make something more "smooth" like the example in this website https://unionbindingcompany.com/

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}
.fa-arrow-right:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/union project/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa5117c01c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Union-U-Orange.png" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>UNION BINDINGS CO.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- nav bar and hearder -->
    <a href="">Product <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}

a:hover > .fa-arrow-right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

You have to change `.fa-arrow-right:hover` to `a:hover > .fa-arrow-right`. All this does is apply styles to `.fa-arrow-right` when `a` is hovered on.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}

a:hover > .fa-arrow-right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/union project/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa5117c01c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Union-U-Orange.png" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>UNION BINDINGS CO.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- nav bar and hearder -->
    <a href="">Product <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! one last question, do you know how to make it stay in 90deg meanwhile you dive into the menu, so then when you close the menu comeback to the start position?

Comment: @AlanDittler Just change `a:hover > .fa-arrow-right` to `a:hover > *`. It works as long as the menu is inside the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `transition:` modifier to smooth things out and `a:hover > i.fa-arrow-right` selector to apply the hover effect to the whole element.

```css
a, i {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}
a:hover > i.fa-arrow-right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/union project/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa5117c01c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Union-U-Orange.png" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>UNION BINDINGS CO.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- nav bar and hearder -->
    <a href="">Product <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only HTML and CSS then you can make it this way:

HTML:

```
<div>
<a class="link" href="#">Product <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}

.link:hover{
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}
.fa-arrow-right{
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}
.link:hover > .fa-arrow-right {
  color: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

If you can consider jQuery you can have it like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
<a class="link-type2" href="#">Product <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* jQuery styles */
.link-type2:hover,  .link-type2:hover *{
  color: red;
}

.icon-rotate-90-animate{
    -webkit-animation: icon-rotate-90 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
    -moz-animation: icon-rotate-90 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
    animation: icon-rotate-90 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes icon-rotate-90{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes icon-rotate-90{
    0%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}

@keyframes icon-rotate-90{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}

.icon-rotate-90-animate-reverse{
    -webkit-animation: icon-rotate-90-reverse 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
    -moz-animation: icon-rotate-90-reverse 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
    animation: icon-rotate-90-reverse 200ms ease-in-out 1 normal both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes icon-rotate-90-reverse{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes icon-rotate-90-reverse{
    0%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes icon-rotate-90-reverse{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var linkType2 = $('.link-type2');
  var arrowRight = $('.fa-arrow-right');
  
  $(linkType2).on('click', function(){
     if($(this).find(arrowRight).hasClass('icon-rotate-90-animate')){
       $(this).find('.fa-arrow-right').removeClass('icon-rotate-90-animate');
       $(this).find('.fa-arrow-right').addClass('icon-rotate-90-animate-reverse');
     }
    else{
      $(this).find('.fa-arrow-right').removeClass('icon-rotate-90-animate-reverse');
      $(this).find('.fa-arrow-right').addClass('icon-rotate-90-animate');
    }
  });
});
```

CodePen:https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/oNxjzXv